# Create list with 3 identical items / repeat with return type

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin there are so many utility methods - is there any method for creating 3 list items like in the following code instead of typing this 3 times?

current code:

```
listOf<Item>(
    Item("abc", 123),
    Item("abc", 123),
    Item("abc", 123),
)
```

looking for something like that (which does not work as repeat returns `Unit`)

```
listOf<Item>(
    repeat(3) { Item("abc", 123) }
)
```

Comment: Do you need distinct reference or not?

Comment: would prefer it, but not needed (it's a data class anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
val list = List(3) {
    Item("abc", 123)
}
```

This will create unique instances